# In Snowflake, Find every city mapped to an employee (from any row) and display them concatenated for every row where this employee is present

Tags: sql, concatenation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using Snowflake, In the example below, I am trying to concatenate all the city values found on any row for each employee and display them all (Concatenated) for each row where the user appears.

Example I have the table below:

| employee | city | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | montreal | blue |
| john | new york | yellow |
| john | yukon | red |
| mark | san francisco | orange |
| mark | baltimore | purple |
| ivan | london | black |

But my Expected result is the one below:

| employee | city | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | montreal ,new york ,yukon | blue |
| john | montreal ,new york ,yukon | yellow |
| john | montreal ,new york ,yukon | red |
| mark | san francisco,baltimore | orange |
| mark | san francisco,baltimore | purple |
| ivan | london | black |

Is there a snowflake query that could help me achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: What does color have to do with anything?

Answer (score 2):

We can try using `LISTAGG()` as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT employee,
       LISTAGG(city, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY city) OVER (PARTITION BY employee) city,
       color
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY employee;
```

Comment: Hi This works, however there is no comma separating each value

Comment: found how to add the delimiter thanks a lot!